# AngularJS call function from a directive in a different file

Tags: angularjs

At first I searched a lot about this question, used some suggestions but couldn't get results.
I had one js file, main.js, where there was only one controller and everything worked fine:

```
var app = angular.module('monitoringApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngCookies', 'angularCharts','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','ngLoadScript','ngRoute','dragtable']);

app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$cookies', '$cookieStore' , '$location', function($scope, $http, $cookies, $cookieStore,$location) { 
//some function which i need to call;
}
```

I've added a library for drag and drop table columns dragtable.js and inside dragEnd() function I want to call some function inside main.js

```
var project = angular.module("dragtable", []);

project.directive('draggable', function($window, $document) {
 function dragEnd($event) {  need to call function inside main.js }
}
```

Please note that I already tried  to use shared service but still getting error undefined on the function which is called.

Comment: If you have some code, throwing some error, and want help with that, then post the code, and post the error.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter in which file you're storing the functions. That said, a `directive` is unlikely to be what you're looking for as a directive is mainly used to be linked to an html element like a widget. Think of it as the controller in the MVC model scheme. It where you can have interaction from/to the ui from the coding standing point. But you can't really call a directive function directly if you don't have access to a directive.

A service on the other hand is just a singleton object that can be injected in a controller or in other places.

What you want is probably this:

```
project.factory('draggable', function () {
  function dragEnd($event) { ... }
  return dragEnd
})
```

And inside your main module:

```
app.controller('mainController', 
  [
    '$scope'
  , '$http'
  , '$cookies'
  , '$cookieStore'
  , '$location'
  , 'draggable'
  , function(
      $scope
    , $http
    , $cookies
    , $cookieStore
    , $location
    , draggable
  ) { 
  //here you can call draggable
  }]
)
```

Here you can see that the draggable function aka `dragEnd` is injected in the controller. This is good if you want to use this common function for multiple handler but then you might need to bind the function to an object like this:

```
var draggable = draggable.bind(someobj)
```

Or use it with `apply` or `call`

```
draggable.call(someobj, event)
draggable.apply(someobj, [event])
```

The reason to do that is that if you want to acces `this` from within the function when it's called, it might not be what it you expect it to be depending on how you're actually calling the method.

Also one note regarding your directive... You always have to return something. In you case chances are that you created the factory but didn't return anything. For this reason you had the "undefined" error. If you don'T return anything the factory will create and delete the function when it's run.